# Scala: Return head of list but empty list can't return Nil

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming, traits

I'm just starting to learn Scala and i'm having a bit of trouble with a head function. I want to return the first element from a list of A elements. But in the case of Nil, I don't know what to return. The function expects A, but as A is abstract and can be anything, i don't know what to return.

When i pass an empty list to my tails function returning Nil works fine.

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]


object List {

         def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match {
                  case Nil => 0
                  case Cons(x,xs) => x + sum(xs)
         }


         def tail[A](xs: List[A]): List[A] = {
                 xs match {
                   case Cons(_, ys) => ys
                   case Nil         => Nil
             }
         }

         def head[A](as: List[A]): A = {
                 as match {
                   case Cons(b, _) => b
                   case Nil         => Nil
             }
    }
}

object e31 {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
                  val ex3: List[Int] = Cons(1, Cons(2, Nil))
                  val ex2: List[Int] = Nil;

                  println(List.sum(ex3)) //3
                  println(List.tail(ex2)) //Nil
                  println(List.tail(ex3)) //cons(2, Nil)
                  //println(List.head(ex3)) //doesn't work

    }
}
```

Any help to understand the problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option to the rescue

```
def head[A](as: List[A]): Option[A] = as match {
 case Cons(b, _) => Some(b)
 case Nil        => None
}
```

Make `head` return `Option`. Using `Option` you can communicate that sometimes the answer is not available or valid. For example: In this case when list is empty `head` operation has no meaning. So, we return `None` value in this case. otherwise when list is non empty we return `Some` valid result.

In order to communicate that the result is not always available we use `Option` as return type

## Compilation error

Below code leads to compilation error because your return type is `A` but you actually return `Nil` which of type `List[A]`

```
def head[A](as: List[A]): A = as match {
 case Cons(b, _) => b
 case Nil         => Nil // expected A found: List[A]
}
```

> Note that this function (head which returns option (above declared)) is called `headOption` in std lib

Comment: Nah, the thing that returns `Option` is usually called [`headOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#headOption:Option[A])...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I know. `head` is the function that OP wrote. (its a custom function). I am just asking OP to change return type. OP can change the name of the function to `headOption`

Answer (score 2):

There is this strange type called `Nothing`. `Nothing` is subtype of everything. In particular, `Nothing` is subtype of `A` (whatever `A` is). You cannot produce any values of type `Nothing` (this type is *uninhabited*). But the `throw` keyword behaves *as if it would "return" `Nothing`*. If the operation is nonsensical, then throwing an exception with a descriptive error message is all you can do:

```
case Cons(h, _) => h
case Nil => throw new NoSuchElementException("`head` called on `Nil`")
```